# Passing selected value in h:selectOneMenu to h:link

Tags: jsf-2.2

I want to pass the selected value of a `h:selectOneMenu` to `h:link` as a view param. The selected value is always empty.
Here's my code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{countryLclController.selectedCountry}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{text['select_country']}" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryLclController.getCountries(request.locale.language)}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" itemValue="#{country.countryName}"/>                                                                                                                                                
    <f:ajax render="visa"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:link id="visa" outcome="Visa_Guide" includeViewParams="true" value="#{text['visa_guide']}">
    <f:param name="country" value="#{countryLclController.selectedCountry}"/>
</h:link>
```

the term country is added to outcome since I have the `f:viewParam` in Visa_Guide.xhtml but country is empty; so the outcome becomes: `Visa_Guide?country=` 
`country` is a String field with getter and setter methods in `countryLclController` managed bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to put my `<h:selectonemenu>` inside `<h:form>`.